# Mute the sound “beep” by MediaRecorder start/stop Android 6

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-sound

How to remove the sound "beep" when the video recording starts using MediaRecorder? To solve this problem I use the following method:

```
private int[] audioStreams = new int[] { AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
            AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
            AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT};

for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) 
{
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioStreams[i], 0, 0);
}
```

But this method works for me only for android versions below 6. Is there a working mode for a android Marshmallow and above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on Android 6.1:

```
((AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,true);
```

and it works

Comment: this method does not work on my device huawei honor 4c. In addition, setStreamMute is deprecated.